# Warning jsonlite in shiny: Input to asJSON(keep_vec_names=TRUE) is a named vector

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, jsonlite

Consider this shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons("type", "Type of plot", choices = c("density", "boxplot")),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output[["plot"]] <- renderPlot({
    if(input$type == "density"){
      ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length)) + geom_density()
    }else{
      ggplot(iris, aes(x = "", y = Sepal.Length)) + geom_boxplot()
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I select the radio button "boxplot", this message from the `jsonlite` package appears in the R console:

> Input to asJSON(keep_vec_names=TRUE) is a named vector. In a future
>   version of jsonlite, this option will not be supported, and named
>   vectors will be translated into arrays instead of objects. If you want
>   JSON object output, please use a named list instead. See ?toJSON.

I would like to understand what's going on. What should I do to not get this message ? I fear that my app will be broken with a future version of `jsonlite`.

Comment: The issue seems to be caused by `x = ""`, try to delete the argument and the message doesn't appear (or use `x = 0` instead).

Comment: @ismirsehregal Thanks, you're right. I can remove this argument and add `scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL)`. But this warning didn't occur with the previous version of shiny. I will report.

Comment: Did you report the issue somewhere? I'm running into the same.

Answer (score 5):

Printing your plot rather than returning the plot object should work:

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons("type", "Type of plot", choices = c("density", "boxplot")),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output[["plot"]] <- renderPlot({
    if(input$type == "density"){
      ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length)) + geom_density()
    }else{
      print(ggplot(iris, aes(x = "", y = Sepal.Length)) + geom_boxplot())
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Great reprex, thanks. I recently ran into this issue and this solution worked for my purposes. Hope this helps someone else with the same problem.

There are also some open issues in `shiny` related to this: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2673