# ShinyFriendlyCaptcha and Jsolinte dont work

Tags: r, shiny, jsonlite

I want to put a captcha in my shiny app. I used `ShinyFriendlyCaptcha` package. This is my MWE. It shows only the captcha. It works well:

```
library(shiny)
library(ShinyFriendlyCaptcha)#devtools::install_github("mhanf/ShinyFriendlyCaptcha")
# UI

ui<-fluidPage(
  sfc_output(
    id = "test",
    sitekey = 'FCMLPPDE8H8IO645',
    lang = "en",
    dark_mode = FALSE,
    eu_endpoint = FALSE,
    theme_bs5 = TRUE
  )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output) {
  # shinyvalidate
  
  # captcha response
  captcha_result <- sfc_server(
    id = "test",
    secret = 'A1T24PTUO6EU091S3HVJC3FRN5UE3JPBQ6UDO3RI3R5NM3VE4J6AQ0A8HC',
    sitekey = 'FCMLPPDE8H8IO645',
    eu_endpoint = FALSE
  )
  
}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Now, I need to build the UI dynamically:

```
library(shiny)
library(ShinyFriendlyCaptcha)#devtools::install_github("mhanf/ShinyFriendlyCaptcha")

ui<-uiOutput("body")

# Server
server <- function(input, output) {

  # captcha response
  captcha_result <- sfc_server(
    id = "test",
    secret = 'A1T24PTUO6EU091S3HVJC3FRN5UE3JPBQ6UDO3RI3R5NM3VE4J6AQ0A8HC',
    sitekey = 'FCMLPPDE8H8IO645',
    eu_endpoint = FALSE
  )
      
  output$body <- renderUI({
    fluidPage(
      sfc_output(
        id = "test",
        sitekey = 'FCMLPPDE8H8IO645',
        lang = "en",
        dark_mode = FALSE,
        eu_endpoint = FALSE,
        theme_bs5 = TRUE
      )
    )
  })
}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This code does not show anything (the app does not fail), and this message appears in the console:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5396
Input to asJSON(keep_vec_names=TRUE) is a named vector. In a future version of jsonlite, this option will not be supported, and named vectors will be translated into arrays instead of objects. If you want JSON object output, please use a named list instead. See ?toJSON.
```

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58448118/warning-jsonlite-in-shiny-input-to-asjsonkeep-vec-names-true-is-a-named-vecto) here, but it does not help. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: (Funny, that warning has been in `jsonlite` since 2015 ... I wonder in which future version they're expecting to change behavior. Ref: https://github.com/jeroen/jsonlite/blame/0134cba18366b1c51c6497f4f97273a8423d8d86/R/asJSON.character.R#L10)

Comment: Is it still working? It's just a `message(.)`, not even a `warning(.)`, and lack of any movement to follow through on change seems to suggest there's nothing wrong and low risk in doing nothing.

Comment: The app does not fail. But shows nothing. Only that message appears in the console. If I make the UI not dynamically (first code), the app works correctly (no message and the app shows the captcha)

Comment: I'm more accustomed to seeing `fluidPage` always outside, never inside a `renderUI`. Have you tried `ui <- fluidPage(uiOutput("body"))`, and then `output$body <- renderUI(sfc_output(..))`?

Comment: I tried and I still receive the same message and the app does no show anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ShinyFriendlyCaptcha::sfc_output` loads some JavaScript which fires when `document.readyState` does not equal `loading` anymore. With a dynamic UI, this state is achieved **before** you try to add your captcha (basically once the static UI is loaded).

Thus, all the setup code won't run, because the JS looks for the appropriate div which it cannot find.

You see that the JavaScript is executed too early if you open the developer console:

[image: Developer console showing the message "FriendlyCaptcha: No div was found with .frc-captcha class"]

With the way how `sfc_output` is currently implemented, I guess you have no luck using it dynamically.

A crude workaround would be to split the HTML and the JS dependencies and use `insertUI` to insert them one after the other:

```r
sfc_output2 <- function (id, sitekey = Sys.getenv("captcha_sitekey"), lang = "en", 
    eu_endpoint = FALSE, theme_bs5 = FALSE, dark_mode = FALSE) {
    bs5_dep <- NULL
    if (isTRUE(theme_bs5)) {
        bs5_dep <- htmlDependency(name = "bs5_dep", version = "0.0.1", 
            package = "ShinyFriendlyCaptcha", src = "assets", 
            stylesheet = c(file = "bs5_style.css"))
        bs5_dep <- tags$style(id = "frc-style", bs5_dep)
    }
    ns <- NS(id)
    language <- c("en", "fr", "de", "it", "nl", "pt", "es", "ca", 
        "da", "ja", "ru", "sv", "el", "uk", "bg", "cs", "sk", 
        "no", "fi", "lt", "lt", "pl", "et", "hr", "sr", "sl", 
        "hu", "ro", "zh", "zh_TW", "vi")
    match.arg(arg = lang, choices = language, several.ok = FALSE)
    captcha_js1 <- htmltools::htmlDependency(name = "friendlyCaptcha1", 
        version = "0.9.10", package = "ShinyFriendlyCaptcha", 
        src = "assets", script = "widget.module.min.js", )
    captcha_js2 <- htmltools::htmlDependency(name = "friendlyCaptcha2", 
        version = "0.9.10", package = "ShinyFriendlyCaptcha", 
        src = "assets", script = "widget.min.js")
    captcha_js3 <- tags$script(paste0("shinyCaptcha = function(response) {\n      Shiny.onInputChange('", 
        ns("captcha_response"), "', response);\n             }"))
    captcha_class <- "frc-captcha"
    if (isTRUE(dark_mode)) {
        captcha_class <- sprintf("%s dark", captcha_class)
    }
    endpoint <- "https://api.friendlycaptcha.com/api/v1/puzzle"
    if (isTRUE(eu_endpoint)) {
        endpoint <- "https://eu-api.friendlycaptcha.eu/api/v1/puzzle"
    }
    captcha <- div(class = captcha_class, `data-lang` = lang, 
        `data-sitekey` = sitekey, `data-callback` = I("shinyCaptcha"), 
        `data-puzzle-endpoint` = endpoint)
    deps <- tagList(bs5_dep, captcha_js1, captcha_js2, captcha_js3)
    input_captcha <- checkboxInput(inputId = ns("captchaId"), 
        label = NULL, value = FALSE)
    input_captcha <- tagAppendAttributes(input_captcha, .cssSelector = "div", 
        style = "display:none;")
    captcha <- tagInsertChildren(input_captcha, after = 1, captcha)
    list(cap = captcha, deps = deps)
}
```

Then you can use `sfc_output2` like this:

```r
library(ShinyFriendlyCaptcha)
library(htmltools)

ui<- fluidPage(
  div(id = "mother")
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # captcha response
  captcha_result <- sfc_server(
    id = "test",
    secret = 'A1T24PTUO6EU091S3HVJC3FRN5UE3JPBQ6UDO3RI3R5NM3VE4J6AQ0A8HC',
    sitekey = 'FCMLPPDE8H8IO645',
    eu_endpoint = FALSE
  )

  cap <- sfc_output2(
    id = "test",
    sitekey = 'FCMLPPDE8H8IO645',
    lang = "en",
    dark_mode = FALSE,
    eu_endpoint = FALSE,
    theme_bs5 = TRUE
  )

  insertUI("#mother", "afterBegin", cap$cap)
  insertUI("#mother", "afterBegin", cap$deps)
}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```